Instalation problem with mrcjkb/haskell-tools.nvim plugin
So, i was trying to use the package in the title, but its not working by nothing. I did how they said to do in the github link, but didnt work. Ive try to use a config exacly as a friend which get to use this pluging, but didnt work too. Then I've try to reinstall from the zero, but it didn't work as well. My haskell and ghci are working, its just a problem which ive being not able to catch :c. Help SOS?
When i open a .hs file:
`Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "`*`":`
`Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: Error executing lua: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: BufReadPost Autocommands for "`*`"..FileType Autocomm`
`ands for "*"..function <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[19]..script /home/draell/.local/share/nvim/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/ftplugin/haskell.lua: Vim(runtime):E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .`
`..haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/config/internal.lua:115: attempt to call field 'joinpath' (a nil value)`
`stack traceback:`
`...haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/config/internal.lua:115: in main chunk`
`[C]: in function 'require'`
`...m/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/internal.lua:11: in main chunk`
`[C]: in function 'require'`
`.../share/nvim/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/ftplugin/haskell.lua:1: in main chunk`
`[C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'`
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>`
`[C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'`
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>`
`stack traceback:`
`[C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'`
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>`
`[C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'`
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>`
`stack traceback:`
`[C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'`
`/usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>`

When i use the checkhealth command:
Error detected while processing BufReadPost Autocommands for "*":
Error executing lua callback: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: Error executing lua: /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: BufReadPost Autocommands for "*"..FileType Autocomm
ands for "*"..function <SNR>1_LoadFTPlugin[19]..script /home/draell/.local/share/nvim/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/ftplugin/haskell.lua: Vim(runtime):E5113: Error while calling lua chunk: .
..haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/config/internal.lua:115: attempt to call field 'joinpath' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        ...haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/config/internal.lua:115: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...m/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/lua/haskell-tools/internal.lua:11: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .../share/nvim/lazy/haskell-tools.nvim/ftplugin/haskell.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_cmd'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:25: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24>
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'nvim_buf_call'
        /usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:24: in function </usr/share/nvim/runtime/filetype.lua:10>

So I'm having problems with my haskell-tools instalation.
update: After updating the nvim, even trying to re-install ghcup, hlsm .. I still not able to use it :P. But the error is now:
Failed to find a HLS version for GHC 9.4.7
Executable names we failed to find: haskell-language-server-9.4.7,haskell-langua
ge-server:  

And yeah, i have already have try to downloaded the 9.4.7 version and set it before installing the hls server too.
1: Try to restart                                                               
Type number and <Enter> or click with the mouse (q or empty cancels):


Try if just nvim-lspconfig works fine for haskell on your machine.
It should be sufficient in most of the cases.

Yeah, but i would lost a lot of features. Use Vscode or Emacs instead of Nvim are two different ways in the same approach :P

@JJoaoll maybe try running hls manually, see if you get anything?
